# Clarification on what a "Transaction" is for HERE maps API

Tags: here-api

I am currently evaluating several mapping API's and I have a question regarding HERE maps and what transactions and requests are.  According to the "Plans" page, 
["For most of our services, a transaction is one server request. For map, satellite and traffic tiles, it's 15 requests."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QG4yq.png), but when I look at my usage page, it says I have generated [756 Map Tile Requests on 9/27](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rur7H.png).  Does this mean I have already generated 756 transactions or do I have to do the math and I've only generated 51 (rounding up) transactions?

Also, I only see "Map Tiles" metric on the usage graph.  I do not see where the initial transactions/requests (request to initiate the map) are counted.  Are these not counted and only map tile requests are?

Any clarification is greatly appreciated!  Thank you In advance!

Answer (score -3):

As of today Aug 2018, google have free monthly 28k [google map load](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage-and-billing). 
average 1k per day.

[User interactions with the map, such as panning, zooming, or switching map layers, do not generate additional map loads.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage-and-billing)

It is more than [here map free 250k transaction per month](https://developer.here.com/plans). 
1 map load could be hundreds of transaction.

google 28k map load >>  [here map 250k transaction](https://developer.here.com/faqs#payment-subscription)

Bing map has free yearly 125k [bing map transaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff859477.aspx),

[Maximum 125,000 cumulative billable transactions per calendar year at no charge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/maps/create-a-bing-maps-key)

**Google map has the most free usage compare to bingmap here map**.

Also **google map saterlite imagery is way better than bing map**.

Bing map imagery is way better than here map. (bing map and here map share some imagery in some kind of place or in some way.... you can tell by right bottom logo remark.)

Conclusion:

***Your first choice should be goolge map***,

***google map give you most free usage + best imagery quality.***

second is bing map, less quality image, less free usage.

last is here map. worst quality of image. less free usage.

1 Google map load means 1 user load 1 html page (with google map). As long as this user does not close this loaded map page, even this user zoom/pan millions times, send million request to interact with server, still count as 1 map load. So google give you the most free usage.

Comment: Satellite imagery varies widely between Google, Bing and HERE so if high resolution is important then you should certainly check the quality with all suppliers. 
Also a typical map load view is usually less than one transaction. Map tiles are 256 pixels square so a 500 x 500 pixel map will usually load 4-8 tiles - making 4-8 requests to the server. At 15 requests per transaction simply loading a 500px map would clock up only half a transaction. Maps requiring considerable interaction might not be so well suited to HERE maps though.
https://developer.here.com/faqs#payment-subscription

Comment: Andy is right. A simple HERE map view is less than 1 transaction and it only loads additional tiles if the user interacts with the map.  If the interaction is not heavy, the user just simply zooms and such then it's very much possible that 1 transaction (15 requests) is enough to serve that user.  If the user does not interact with the map at all (e.g. it's just shows a place under some other info) then even multiple users may be served with 1 transaction (15 requests).

Comment: 1 Google map load means 1 user load 1 html page (with google map). As long as this user does not close this loaded map page, even this user zoom/pan millions times, send million request to interact with server, still count as 1 map load. So google give you the most free usage.

Comment: Users dont't pan/zoom millions of times. Users may not even touch the map if it only displays a location. On one my pages google's 28K loads per month is not enough, because it has more than a 1000 daily map loads, but a HERE map can comfortably display those without runnning out of quota.